# What exactly does .gitignore

Tags: git, github

I made some tests to understand what is .gitignore doing to my repository but i still cannot catch exactly its behavior.

Here are the steps i performed during my test, i would like to understand if i'm getting something wrong:

- Initialize a git repo
- Add a .gitignore file

[image]

- Commit it
- Add an 'ignored' file to the repo
- Add a 'not ignored' file to the repo
- git status

Here is the full git bash log:

```
~/Documents/gittest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/DoktorUzi/Documents/gittest/.git/

~/Documents/gittest (master)
$ git add .gitignore.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

~/Documents/gittest (master)
$ git commit -s -m "_TESTGIT"
[master (root-commit) e37661f] _TESTGIT
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore.txt

~/Documents/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

~/Documents/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        README.md
        example_gitignore.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Now, i think that i'm doing something wrong using gitignore, otherwise i'm not understanding how this i useful, if all files new and ignored both appear in the untracked files.

However, what i would like to obtain is a clear distinction between new files and new files which are ignored by gitignore (possibly hiding them from git status).

Comment: your `.gitignore.txt` file should not be a `.txt` file but simply a `.gitignore` file

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_ignoring and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Solved, Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

As commenters noted, the file needs to be named `.gitignore`, not `.gitignore.txt`.

The real key to understanding `.gitignore` entries, though, is to understand Git's *index*.  Unless you know about the index, and how Git uses it, several things will be very mysterious.

A file that is in your work-tree, but not in Git's index, is an *untracked file*.  Listing an untracked file's name, or a pattern that matches its name, in a `.gitignore` file tells `git status` to *shut up* about it—to not call it out as untracked—and also prevents `git add` from copying the file *into* Git's index.  If the file *is* in Git's index, though, listing the file's name in a `.gitignore` has no effect on Git's storing of the file.

#### Long

The first thing to realize is that Git is not so much about files, or branches: Git is instead all about *commits*.  Each commit stores a full and complete snapshot of *all* your files—or at least, all the ones you tell it to snapshot.  Once a commit is made, it is frozen for all time.  That commit, as identified by its unique hash ID—a big ugly string of letters and digits like [`9fadedd637b312089337d73c3ed8447e9f0aa775`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fadedd637b312089337d73c3ed8447e9f0aa775), for instance—will always contain exactly those files, plus the metadata saying who made the commit, when, and so on.  They're stored in a special, read-only, Git-only format that only Git can understand.

The second thing to realize is that since files stored inside Git's commits are read-only and Git-only like this, Git would be completely useless if it did not have a way to *extract* those files *out* of a commit into someplace you can work on and with them.  That work area, where Git extracts the files into usable form—ordinary files that the rest of your computer can use—is your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

Hence, after selecting some particular commit, there are *two* sets of files: the frozen ones in the commit, and the editable ones in your work-tree.  You can't actually see, or do anything with, the frozen ones.  All you can do is use the work-tree copies—but that's all you need.

Git could stop here.  Mercurial, which is another distributed version control system (DVCS) like Git, *does* stop here.  With Mercurial, you extract a commit into your work-tree, then make changes, then commit.  Mercurial builds the new commit from whatever is in your work-tree.  But Git doesn't do that.  Instead, Git inserts a *third* copy of each file, in between the frozen, Git-only copy in the commit, and the usable copy in your work-tree.<sup>1</sup>

These extra copies of every file, which are in the frozen format—but not actually frozen—are most of what the index is all about.  Git also calls this index the *staging area*, because of the way Git *uses* the index.  The frozen-format copies of each file, in the index, are going to be what goes into the *next* commit you make.

When you run `git commit`, what Git does is:

- gather metadata, such as your name and email address and a log message
- add on appropriate stuff like the current date and time, and the hash ID of the current commit as the new commit's parent
- freeze all the files that are in the index

and write that out as the new commit.  It doesn't even *look* at your work-tree: it builds the new commit from what's in the *index* instead.<sup>2</sup>

In other words, a simple way to describe the index is that it contains *the files that you propose to put in the next commit you make*.<sup>3</sup>  The index is initially filled in from a commit that you chose with `git checkout`, or in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`.  Your work-tree, which is otherwise for *your* usage, is likewise filled in from these files.  Then you can make any changes you like in your work-tree.  The copies in the index are not yet changed!

When you run `git add` on a work-tree file, Git *copies the work-tree copy into the index*, compressing it into the special Git-only format in the process.  That file overwrites whatever used to be in the index under that name.

If the file is totally new to the repository, i.e., has never been seen before, it won't be in the index *yet*.  If the file is in some commit in the repository, but not in the commit you *chose* with `git checkout`, the file won't be in the index now either.  In this case, `git add` writes the file into the index, and now it's in the index.  So the index can hold files that *didn't* come out of the commit at all, or it can hold updated copies of files that *did* come out of the commit.

You can also *remove* a file from the index.  Running `git rm path` removes both the index copy of the named file *and* the work-tree copy.  Now that the file isn't in the index, it is not in the proposed next commit.  If you commit now, it *won't* be in the commit.

When you run `git status`, Git starts by comparing the current commit to the contents of its index.  For each file that is *the same* here, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git says that this file is *staged for commit*.  A file that's gone missing—that is in the current commit, but not in the index at all—is staged for deletion, and a file that's new in the index is staged as a new file.

Git then, however, goes on to run a *second* comparison.  This time, it compares the files in the index to the files in your work-tree.  Again, each file can either match, or be different, or be missing—or, you can have files in your work-tree that aren't in your index at all.  For a file that matches, Git says nothing at all.  For a file that doesn't match, Git says *not staged for commit*.  For a file that is missing in your work-tree, Git says that a deletion is not staged for commit.  The one thing that's special here is that if a file is *new*, Git doesn't say "new", it says instead *untracked*.

Side note: Git's copies of files in Git's index just have long names—`path/to/file.ext`, for instance, is just a file name, not a folder `path` holding a sub-folder named `to` holding a file named `file.ext`.  This is why you can't store an empty directory in Git: Git doesn't store directories at all, as there's no index entry of type "directory", and Git builds new commits from what's in its index.  If you could get an empty directory into the index, Git could store an empty directory.  But you can only get files, symbolic links, and *gitlinks* (submodule information) into the index.<sup>4</sup>  Whenever Git goes to extract a commit that contains a *file* whose name is `path/to/file.ext`, Git knows to create the containing `path` and `path/to` directories/folders if necessary.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index holds *references to* Git *blob objects*, rather than actual copies of the file data.  Unless you start using the low level `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` commands, though, you don't need to care about this distinction.  It suffices to think of the index as holding a third copy of each file.

<sup>2</sup>If you use `git commit -a`, Git will, in effect, run `git add -u` first, before committing.  There are a number of sneaky issues here that I won't get into, but what this does is auto-add only those files that are *already in the index*.  So it only *almost* lets you not care about the index: it falls down in several spots, including the totally-new-file case.

<sup>3</sup>This is somewhat oversimplified.  The index has additional functions.  The biggest one—the one you'll eventually encounter and need to know about—is that the index takes on an expanded role during a conflicted merge.  We won't get into this here, though.

<sup>4</sup>Someone noticed that this provides a sneaky way to let Git store an empty directory.  Since a submodule is itself a directory, you simply store, as your submodule, a link to a completely empty extra repository.  With no commits in that repository, nothing can get checked out into that subdirectory.  That provides you with an empty directory.  This *works*, but it feels a little odd.

---

#### Ignoring—i.e., not complaining about and not adding—files automatically

Git is often used to save source files for compiled (or byte-compiled, as in Python) languages.  These compilers tend to write out a lot of files that you *don't* want kept version-controlled.  It's handy to be able to say: *ignore all `*.o` files*, for instance, or *ignore all files found in `__pycache__` directories*.

Git's `.gitignore` files are a mechanism for this.  Their format is a little bit complicated because OSes tend to store files as entries within *directories* or *folders*, and Git has to accommodate these OSes.  So:

- A name with no special characters means *ignore any file with this name, even if it appears in some subdirectory*.
- A name with a leading slash, as in `/program-x`, means *ignore the file with this name in **this** directory, but not in subdirectories*.
- A name with an embedded slash, as in `sub/program-x`, means *ignore the file with name `sub/program-x` as seen from this directory*.  This will not ignore `other/program-x`, nor will it ignore `sub/sub/program-x`: only `sub/program-x` counts here.
- A name of the form `sub/` means *ignore a **directory** (aka folder) with this name, but not a **file** with this name*.  This means that files in `a/sub/` get ignored too, but a *file* named `b/sub` is not ignored.  (This rule itself is a little odd, but very useful for the negation rules below.)  Adding a leading slash "anchors" the name to this directory.
- Last, starting an entry with `!` tells Git *not* to ignore this after all.  This is particularly useful with those directory patterns.

On top of these, you can add the glob pattern character `*` to match any file, for instance, or other shell-glob-style characters as listed in [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Suppose, for instance, that you'd like Git to not complain about untracked files anywhere inside `vendor/` *except* for any file you've put in `vendor/patches/`.  To do this, you must make sure that Git scans the *directory* named `vendor` for files and sub-directories, which you do by writing:

```
vendor/*
!vendor/patches/
```

The first line ignores *all* things—directories *and* files—inside `vendor`, but still scans `vendor` itself.  The second line says that when Git comes across `vendor/patches` and it's a directory, *do* scan it and *don't* ignore its files.  The later `!` line overrides the earlier `*` line.  Hence a directory named `vendor/a/` and a file named `vendor/description` both get ignored, but `vendor/patches/` gets searched for files to complain about as being untracked.

#### En-masse `add` operations

When you run `git add`, you can give it individual file names:

```
git add main.py
git add README.md
```

for instance.  But you can also do en-masse "add everything" operations with:

```
git add .
```

or:

```
git add *
```

These are subtly different when your *shell* does the `*` expansion, as `git add *` won't invoke `git add` on a file named, e.g., `.pylintrc`, but `git add .` will see `.pylintrc` and will try to add it.

These en-masse operations add *every* file that Git can find this way, *except* that if a file is currently untracked—is in your work-tree, but not in the index—this `git add` will *skip* the file, and not add it.

#### Hence the name `.gitignore` is a bit of a lie

A better name for this file would be `.git-do-not-complain-about-untracked-files-and-do-not-auto-add-these-files-when-using-an-en-masse-add-operation`.  But imagine trying to create that file name in a new repository.

There's one other subtle feature / bug here: listing a file, or a pattern, in `.gitignore` gives Git permission to *clobber* the file in some corner cases.  These do not come up very often, but when they do, they can be annoying.  It would be nice if you could mark certain files as *ignored but precious: never overwrite or remove this file*.  [For details, see this rather long mail thread.](https://public-inbox.org/git/4C6A1C5B.4030304@workspacewhiz.com/T/)

#### Gitignore files can appear in subdirectories

It's pretty common to have one top level `.gitignore` file listing the names of compiled binaries and object files (`*.o`, `*.a`, `*.so`, etc.).  But you might also want to allow a subdirectory to specifically ignore some file(s).  For instance, suppose you have a large project with a library and a bunch of different programs that use the library.  Each compiled program might be a subdirectory of the top level repository, with the library also a subdirectory.  It makes sense, in each program's directory, to create a `.gitignore` at that level, that ignores that compiled program's executable image.  That way the top level `.gitignore` only lists those things that are common across *all* sub-directories.  The `lib/.gitignore` file might have the `*.a` pattern in it, as there are no archives built in the program directories.  The documentation directory might list program-built (non-human-created) cross-reference files or other generated files that don't appear in non-documentation directories, and so on.

An *empty* `.gitignore` file is allowed: it adds nothing to the set of things to ignore, but can occupy an otherwise-empty directory.  You can add this `.gitignore` file to the set of files in Git's index, so that Git will create the directory later, when checking out this commit.